# Kafka Stream Subscription Error - Invalid Version

Tags: java, apache-kafka

When attempting to connect to a topic from Java jetty microservice, I’m getting this Kafka internal version mismatch error:

```
stream-thread [App-94d44dcd-f1d4-49a6-9dd3-8d4eee06f82a-StreamThread-1] Encountered the following error during processing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: version must be between 1 and 3; was: 4
                at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.assignment.SubscriptionInfo.<init>(SubscriptionInfo.java:67)
                at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.subscription(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:312)
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.metadata(ConsumerCoordinator.java:176)
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.sendJoinGroupRequest(AbstractCoordinator.java:515)
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.initiateJoinGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:466)
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:412)
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:352)
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:337)
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:333)
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1218)
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1175)
                at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1154)
                at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:861)
                at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:814)
                at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
                at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
```

Any ideas on what could cause such an exception?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For useful answer please provide more information. What is topic configuration both on Kafka and consumer side? Please show us code for consumer, entity classes. What data is stored in Kafka topic ?

Comment: What version of Kafka is the server? What is your client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had come across this error myself and it is most likely because you have used non-unique APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG and/or CLIENT_ID_CONFIG

```
// Give the Streams application a unique name.  The name must be unique in the Kafka cluster
// against which the application is run.
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-app");
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "my-client");
```